# Why is my text not displaying after image?

Tags: html, css

i am programming a basic webpage and have trouble with displaying a line of text after an image. In the code below, after the image as labelled by `id=image`, i plan to include another line of text with the `p` attribute under the `<p>hi</p>` below but somehow the text is not showing, may I know what is the problem?

Is there something wrong with my css coding? I have already set the margin to the right px but still the text does'nt seem to be appearing.

Below is the portion of the code:

```
  <div id="logo">
  <img src = "C:\Users\GFYU-PC\Desktop\GHnotes\image\logo.png"/>
  </div>

  <ul id="navigation">
  <li><a href="C:\Users\GFYU-PC\Desktop\GHnotes\index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="C:\Users\GFYU-PC\Desktop\GHnotes\Album.html">Album</a></li>
  <li><a href="C:\Users\GFYU-PC\Desktop\GHnotes\Whatsapp.html">Whatsapp</a></li>

  <ul id="imgn">
  <li>Before</li>
  <li>Main Page</li>
  <li>Next</li>
  </ul>  

  <div id="image">
  <img src="C:\Users\GFYU-PC\Desktop\GHnotes\image\Album\image\4.jpg" alt="Click!" height = "400px" width= "600px">
  </div>

  <p>hi</p>
```

Comment: you did not close your `li` and `ul` tag

Comment: I can still see the text even with the broken tags. Where is your CSS?

Comment: I think it is a bug, when I paste the code on a new note, it is able to run perfectly. However, it can't seem to run on the original one. This is weird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li><a href="C:\Users\GFYU-PC\Desktop\GHnotes\index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="C:\Users\GFYU-PC\Desktop\GHnotes\Album.html">Album</a></li>
  <li><a href="C:\Users\GFYU-PC\Desktop\GHnotes\Whatsapp.html">Whatsapp</a></li
```

it must be:

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li><a href="C:\Users\GFYU-PC\Desktop\GHnotes\index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="C:\Users\GFYU-PC\Desktop\GHnotes\Album.html">Album</a></li>
  <li><a href="C:\Users\GFYU-PC\Desktop\GHnotes\Whatsapp.html">Whatsapp</a></li></ul>
```

You forgot  `</li>` and the `</ul>`